# Why does the exif data show a max aperture 1.6 when I am using a f/1.8 lens?

Tags: nikon, aperture, metadata

I am looking at exif data of one of my image that i took with Nikon 35mm f/1.8 lens. While the exif information of my actual aperture is correct, max aperture displayed is 1.6 for the lens which is actually f/1.8!  I am wondering how this is possible ?

[image]